# Is there a way to enter dynamically data into a lua script using C#?

Tags: c#, lua

I am trying to implement the following logic using C#/Lua:

Inside my C# application, I have a form with a textbox that allows me to enter a signal value and pass it then to the Lua script via (state["timeToCollection"] = signalValue.Text;). The idea is that when this value is equal to "low", some other calls will happen.

The issue that I am facing currently is that this signalValue.Text needs to be filled out before executing the Lua script and not after executing it (desired behavior). Is there a way to do this dynamically, meaning, I execute the Lua script, Lua script checks for signalValue.Text value, if the value is not low, it just keeps running until the user enters low in the form.

Thanks

C#

```
state.DoFile(luaScriptFile); //execute lua script

state["timeToCollection"] = signalValue.Text; // pass signal value
```

Lua Script:

```
function DM()
     while (timeToCollision == 'low') 
     do
        UDC:eventImageDataReq('AutoHitch',01)
     end
        
end

DM()
```

Comment: What c# library are you using to execute lua code?

Answer (score 0):

You have the Lua interpreter, so to set a variable simply set it:

```
state.DoString($"timeToCollision = '{signalValue.Text}'");
```

You didn't mention what flavor of C# Lua bindings you're using, but for example `MoonSharp`, since it's a fully managed re-implementation of Lua, exposes the variable tables directly, so you can use something like `state.Globals["timeToCollision"]` to set your values directly, without having to parse and execute Lua code.

Comment: Exposing the variables directly might no work in this case since I need the Lua script to be the one implementing the logic and not the other way around until the low value is passed from the c# application. Currently the problem I am facing is that the whole c# from gets frozen as soon the Lua script enters the while loop :/